# Rails: Multiple records created in a single ajax query

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am unable to understand how a same record can be created at same time in rails, below are the two records which is created when a single ajax request is sent. This is not happening all the time, but only rarely, but I am not sure how to solve this is, any help would be great, Thanks in advance.

```
#<PostComment id: 932, comment_id: 3, post_id: 371, created_at: "2013-10-28 11:14:23", updated_at: "2013-10-28 11:28:49">
#<PostComment id: 933, comment_id: 3, post_id: 371, created_at: "2013-10-28 11:14:23", updated_at: "2013-10-28 11:14:23">
```

Comment: Are you sure there aren't two ajax requests in those rare cases? Anyway, you could check if a comment has been submitted twice by not allowing a comment's body to be the same as the comment before (e.g. in an ActiveRecord `before_save` filter).

Comment: I already have a before_create to find any existing record and delete it, but it is not finding, my guess is, since it is creating in same time, it is not able to find it.

Comment: You're right, the data won't have been committed to the database just then. If you'd like to consider unfancy but ugly coding style, you could try an `after_commit` callback comparing the last two comment bodies and doing something if he finds a duplicate. If you want to get fancy, you'd maybe cache the last comment body in redis or memcached and compare against this one. A custom `validate :comment_must_not_be_duplicate` could then make a request to redis et al. and see if there is some kind of duplication. I'm sure there are other, nicer options out there, too.

Comment: Be aware that some people double-click on links :-). If the javascript doesn't detect this, it could fire off 2 ajax requests almost at the same time. And if you have bad luck, the first record isn't created while the second one checks for duplicates.